# single-click an application

Tags: startup-applications

Is there an add-on/extension/package that will allow an application to be opened with a single click?
There is not an option to open an application with a single click.  In Files there is a Preferences option to open *files* and *directories* with a single click but that does not affect Ubuntu applications.

Comment: Gnome desktop environment does open applications with single click, you should give it a try (but its not an answer to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Files* application is a file manager, not an application launcher. If you open the *Applications* view of the dash in *Unity*, or click any icons on the *Launcher* on the left of the screen, a single click will open the application.

You really shouldn't use the *Files* application as a means for launching applications generally.

Comment: Thanks very much dobey.
Just for completeness and for others who might be transitioning from Windows the Applications view of The Dashboard is accessed by Super-a (pressing the Super and the a keys simultaneously; the Super is usually to the left of the spacebar and is AKA the windows key; pressing and holding the super gives a slew of hot-keys).

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Hardware Settings > Input Devices > Mouse

Click the RadioButton which says "Single-Click to open files and folders"

then click Apply and that's it.